# Firefox not executing statements after submit

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have JSP where i submit a form using javascript. Its a popup window so after submission popup must be closed. I used following code:

```
document.forms["formname"].submit();
window.close();
```

Problem is - Form gets submitted successfully but window doesnt get closed.
Its work fine in IE.

Comment: form gets submitted and redirects the browser to the result page. i think the code doesn't reach `window.close()` anymore.

Comment: Congrates.. for IE Support pulkit :). Rarely we find something support in IE and not in Mozilla Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I have a doubt how it is working in IE.
Javascript doesn't have any control after/until you submit the form and control is returned back to the browser. You should use some another mechanism to close the window after submission of form.

Comment: I want to add here :- previously i wrote like :-
document.formname.submit();
window.close();
in this case firefox was closing window but was not submitting the form. this code is inside a javascript function which is called on onclick event.

Comment: No not yet!! Either ways one of required actions are nt happening..
Either it Submit form or it closes window. but both should happen together.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of closing the window from a script running in the context of the window to be closed, try closing it from the context of the window that opened it. For example:

```
var popup;

function pop() {
  popup = window.open('foo', 'mypopup', 'menubar=no,location=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=no');
  console.log(popup);
}

function unpop() {
  popup.close(); // close the popup
}
```

This works for me in Firefox. You can test it live [here](http://jsbin.com/ogotop/edit#javascript,live).

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, once you submit the form, you've turned over control to the browser and there is no guarantee that any more javascript in that page will execute.  It may just immediately start loading the result page.  As such, you have several options:

1. You can make the result page close itself.  So, when the result page loads after the submit, it contains its own `window.close()`.
2. You can use ajax instead of a form submit to send the data to your server.  Then, the lines after the ajax code sends the data will execute.  To be safe, you may want to wait until the ajax call returns successfully before closing the window (depending upon what you're doing and how important it is to know whether it succeeded or not).
3. You can control things from the parent window that opened the form and close things from there.